# Azure Postgres AD Authentication

Tags: postgresql, azure

We are looking at having multiple databases in a Single Server setting on Azure Database for Postgres SQL.

[image]

Per documentation at [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-aad-authentication)

- Customers can manage database permissions using external (Azure AD)
  groups.
- Azure AD authentication uses PostgreSQL database roles to
  authenticate identities at the database level
- Support of token-based
  authentication for applications connecting to Azure Database for
  PostgreSQL

Has anyone tried doing this i.e. databaseA and databaseB with permission to ADGroupA and ADGroupB respectively, under single Azure DB server instance ?  Does this give complete data isolation between the different databaseA and databaseB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use 2 separate AD groups on 2 different databases for access control on a single server. Two different users will have access to their own database.